# Scientific publications and related software sourcecode

Tags: publications, code

I want to create a dataset (offline, only for my research purposes) based on scientific publications (research papers), which are somehow connected to software source code (for example given by a git-repository). The research domains of the publications are irrelevant, as long as they are talking about related software source code (for example by mentioning functions or variables).

In order to create the dataset, I need journals/websites where papers and their related code are listed. I already found the [Journal of Open Research Software](http://openresearchsoftware.metajnl.com/), which fits my requirements, but I am pretty sure there are more resources like this out there.

**How can I find publication venues in which papers regularly include links to related source code?**

Comment: I don't see any question mark in your question. So, what is your question? If you want a list of such sites, sorry, we do not take shopping questions.

Comment: You can just get a DOI for your dataset/code, without having to publish it in a journal.

Comment: https://guides.github.com/activities/citable-code/

Comment: @scaaahu I thought the question is quite obvious - I am in need for ressources where I can find research papers related with code. I already searched a lot. I thought maybe someone knows such a journal and can help me.

Comment: See e.g. https://www.journals.elsevier.com/computer-physics-communications/

Comment: Even so I answered to this question, the Open Data SE might be a better place to ask.

Comment: The ACM Transactions on Mathematics Software ("TOMS") publishes a lot of papers on software.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to extract this information from the **Related identifiers** of Zenodo software records (the related identifiers that are marked as *Supplement to*).

Here are two examples:

- https://zenodo.org/record/345130
- https://zenodo.org/record/570830

This is the [search for all software records](https://zenodo.org/search?page=1&size=20&q=&type=software) in the database:

Zenodo offers data following the crawling protocol [OAI-PMH](http://developers.zenodo.org/#oai-pmh). So harvesting this information should be managable.